# Getting Basic Profile Info through Linkedin API from salesforce

Tags: api, rest, salesforce, linkedin-api, apex-code

I am trying to get basic profile info from Linkedin API in APEX, i got authorization token and secret token but not able to retrieve basic profile using the token. please find below the code :

```
public void getLinkedinData(){
    List<TestLinkedin__c> tok = [select unAuth_Key__c,unAuth_Token__c from TestLinkedin__c where name='AuthKey' limit 1];  
    oauth_token = tok[0].unAuth_Token__c;
    oauth_token_secret = tok[0].unAuth_Key__c;        

    unAuthorisedToken =  tok[0].unAuth_Token__c;
    unAuthorisedKey = tok[0].unAuth_Key__c;  

    nonceValue  = generateNonce(); 
    timeStamp = generateTimeStamp();     

    string TripItAccessDataUri='https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~/format/json';

    Http h = new Http();
    HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
    req.setMethod('GET');
    req.setEndpoint(TripItAccessDataUri);
    final String oAUth_BASE_signature = SignatureBaseStringForAccessData(TripItAccessDataUri,unAuthorisedToken,unAuthorisedKey,nonceValue,timeStamp); 
    String signature = SignatureForAccessData(oAUth_BASE_signature ,consumerKey_Secret+'&'+unAuthorisedKey);
    req.setHeader('Authorization','OAuth realm=\"https://api.linkedin.com/\",oauth_consumer_key=\"'+oauth_consumer_key+'\",oauth_token=\"'+unAuthorisedToken+'\",oauth_nonce=\"'+nonceValue+'\",oauth_token_secret=\"'+unAuthorisedKey+'\",oauth_signature_method=\"'+oauth_signature_method+'\",oauth_timestamp=\"'+timeStamp +'\",oauth_version=\"'+oauth_version+'\",oauth_signature=\"'+signature+'\"');  
    reqstr =oAUth_BASE_signature ;
    HttpResponse res = h.send(req);
    resData =  res.getBody();
    system.debug('&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&& Respose' + resData );
}   

public String generateNonce(){
    String nonce;
    String finalNonce ;  
    nonce = String.valueOf(Math.abs(Math.random())); 
    finalNonce = nonce.substring(nonce.indexOf('.')+1,nonce.length());
    System.debug('+++++++++Nonce '+ finalNonce );
    return finalNonce ;
} 
public long generateTimeStamp(){
    long millis = (long) System.currentTimeMillis() ;
    long sysTime = (long) millis / 1000;
    System.debug('+++++++++++++TimeStamp'+ sysTime );
    return sysTime ;
}

public String SignatureBaseStringForAccessData(String TripItAccessDataUri,String unAuthorisedToken,String unAuthorisedKey,String  nonceValue ,Long timeStamp) {
    String httpmethod = 'GET';
    String oAUTH_PARA='oauth_consumer_key='+oauth_consumer_key+'&oauth_nonce='+nonceValue +'&oauth_signature_method='+oauth_signature_method+'&oauth_timestamp='+timeStamp+'&oauth_token='+unAuthorisedToken+'&oauth_token_secret='+unAuthorisedKey+'&oauth_version='+oauth_version+'';
    String BASE_STRING = httpmethod+'&'+EncodingUtil.urlEncode(TripItAccessDataUri,'UTF-8')+'&'+EncodingUtil.urlEncode(oAUTH_PARA,'UTF-8');
    return BASE_STRING;
}

//Signature Generator for Data
public String SignatureForAccessData(String Signature_Base_Value,String Key){
    Blob mac = Crypto.generateMac('HmacSHA1',Blob.valueOf(Signature_Base_Value),Blob.valueOf(Key));
    String macUrl = EncodingUtil.urlEncode(EncodingUtil.base64Encode(mac),'UTF-8');
    System.debug('++++++++Final Signature Is '+macUrl );   
    return macUrl;
}
```

Response body:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<error>
    <status>401</status>
    <timestamp>1354429511382</timestamp>
    <request-id>GDGNWB2M1V</request-id>
    <error-code>0</error-code>
    <message>[unauthorized].OAU:tylg6udljqe0|e7820b33-6acc-4752-b014-f54d505cf‌​8a0|*01|*01:1354376252:vufYE2Zeg9Dg/R1YXO21cRlfmPA=</message>
</error>
```

Comment: What error messages are you getting back?

Comment: I am getting the below response :
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?> 
<error> 
 <status>401</status> 
 <timestamp>1354429511382</timestamp> 
 <request-id>GDGNWB2M1V</request-id> 
 <error-code>0</error-code> 
 <message>     [unauthorized].OAU:tylg6udljqe0|e7820b33-6acc-4752-b014-f54d505cf8a0|*01|*01:1354376252:vufYE2Zeg9Dg/R1YXO21cRlfmPA=
 </message> 
</error>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally got the answer....

issue was with the special character '~'

Use the below URl to fetch the profile details by repacing '~' with '%7E'

string LinkedInAccessDataUri='https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/%7E';

Answer (score 0):

You need to ask permission for the r_basicprofile during authentication:

Rest sample request:

`https://api.linkedin.com/uas/oauth/requestToken?scope=r_basicprofile`

Javascript sample request:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://platform.linkedin.com/in.js">
    api_key: your_api_key
    scope: r_basicprofile
</script>
```

Here is a list for all fields along with their required permissions:

[Linkedin API profile fields](https://developer.linkedin.com/documents/profile-fields)

Comment: But when i tried giving the below URI while making request, i got invalid signature issue :
https://api.linkedin.com/uas/oauth/requestToken?scope=r_basicprofile

Comment: This is not due to the request URL used, it is due to you sending an incorrect signature to the linkedin server. Try using a different library to see if this solves your issue.